# Unable to resolve path to module error while linting my React + JS project using Vite

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, eslint, vite

**Folder Structure: *- src/assets/images/react.svg***

I am using the import statement in App.jsx as:

`import reactLogo from '@images/react.svg';`

And, the error message is:

`2:23  error  Unable to resolve path to module '@images/react.svg'  import/no-unresolved`

[Path Aliasing Not Working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1EYV.png)

I tried modifying the paths in `.jsconfig.json` and `vite.config.js` to use relative as well as absolute paths.
Also, while I am trying to import the image in `App.jsx`, it shows `@images` as a suggestion to import the image from but, it does not show the content inside that folder it is referring to.

**dependencies and devDependencies in package.json**

```json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^3.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.27.5",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "stylelint-order": "^6.0.2",
    "vite": "^4.1.0",
    "vite-plugin-eslint": "^1.8.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.21.0",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.19.1",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.2",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
    "@types/node": "^18.14.1",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.27",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.10",
    "eslint": "^8.34.0",
    "eslint-config": "^0.3.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^19.0.4",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^15.0.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.7.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.32.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "prettier": "^2.8.4",
    "stylelint": "^15.2.0",
    "stylelint-config-recommended": "^10.0.1"
  }
}
```

**.eslintrc file**

```json
{
  "extends": ["airbnb", "prettier"],
  "plugins": ["react", "import", "react-hooks", "prettier"],
  "rules": {
    "react/jsx-filename-extension": [1, { "extensions": [".js", ".jsx"] }],
    "react/react-in-jsx-scope": "off",
    "react/jsx-props-no-spreading": "off",
    "prettier/prettier": "error"
  },
  "parser": "@babel/eslint-parser",
  "parserOptions": {
    "sourceType": "module",
    "allowImportExportEverywhere": true
  },
  "settings": {
    "react": {
      "version": "detect"
    },
    "import/resolver": {
      "node": {
        "paths": ["./src"],
        "extensions": [".js", ".jsx"],
        "moduleDirectory": ["./", "node_modules"]
      }
    }
  },
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "node": true
  }
}
```

**vite.config.js**

```
import path from 'path';

import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import eslintPlugin from 'vite-plugin-eslint';

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    react(),
    eslintPlugin({
      include: ['./src/**/*.jsx', './src/**/*.js'],
      fix: true,
    }),
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@components': path.resolve(__dirname, './src/components/'),
      '@images': path.resolve(__dirname, './src/assets/images/'),
      '@fonts': path.resolve(__dirname, './src/assets/fonts/'),
    },
  },
});
```

**.jsconfig.json**

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "@components": ["src/components/"],
      "@images": ["src/assets/images/"],
      "@fonts": ["src/assets/fonts/"]
    }
  }
}
```